# Access user location on facebook app (React.JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-instant-games

I am building a products review app with react for a certain company. They require the user's location(country) to show suitable products to review in case users open the app on their own.
So, I only found getLocale() in instant games SDK and it's impossible for me to know the user's country through this function, only language is available. I tried react-facebook-login but there doesn't seem to be a permission that gives you location(country) either. I only found one named 'user_location'. However, I couldn't find it on the permissions to request list on facebook dashboard. I also read that I cannot use any third party library that gives me access to user's information outside facebook's sdk.

Any thoughts on how to go through this?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered *asking* the user for their location? Or using the HTML5 geolocation API?

Comment: you can only ask users for location if it's through facebook api feature which I cannot find right now not sure why. And I can't use geolocation API because that will violate facebook rules for user info protection.

Comment: I strongly suspect you've misunderstood the rules a bit. Can you point to the specific policies you're worried about? The idea that using the Facebook API means you can't ask a user for their address (what are you supposed to do if they order a product and you need to ship it?) is a bit out there.

Comment: To be honest, someone else told me about the rules thing I didn't read it. So, Are you sure that it's safe to use geolocation and google maps to get user's country?

Comment: I'm quite certain that you can use Facebook's login via the SDK and still use normal browser/device geolocation APIs, yes.

Comment: alright then. I'll just go with that. Thank you :-)